# How to make type stable generator with a while condition like map?

Tags: types, julia, list-comprehension, control-flow

Say I'm simulating an experiment and I don't know when the step will terminate. With the `while` condition and pushing to an array of `Any`, the function isn't type stable.

```
function simulate()
    result = []
    alive = true
    while alive
        push!(result,alive)
        alive = rand(Bool)
    end
    return result
end
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in a type stable way?

Comment: `result = fill(true, rand(Distributions.Geometric(0.5)) + 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very easy fix in this particular case! You can specify an empty `Array{Bool}` instead of the `Array{Any}` you are currently getting by simply writing `Bool[]` in place of `[]`:

```
function simulate()
    result = Bool[]
    alive = true
    while alive
        push!(result,alive)
        alive = rand(Bool)
    end
    return result
end
```

Looking at the output of a `@code_warntype` on this modified function, we can see that the result is now stably inferred as a `Vector{Bool}`

```
julia> @code_warntype simulate()
MethodInstance for simulate()
  from simulate() in Main at REPL[13]:1
Arguments
  #self#::Core.Const(simulate)
Locals
  alive::Bool
  result::Vector{Bool}
Body::Vector{Bool}
1 ─     (result = Base.getindex(Main.Bool))
│       Main.sizehint!(result, 50)
└──     (alive = true)
2 ┄     goto #4 if not alive
3 ─     Main.push!(result, alive::Core.Const(true))
│       (alive = Main.rand(Main.Bool))
└──     goto #2
4 ─     return result
```

Comment: Thanks! I had actually trimmed down the example to make a MWE. In my actual function, it would be returning a mixed type named tuple. Is there a more general way that the iteration can create it's own resulting array (like how map does)?

Comment: Hmm, I would have to have a better idea of what your other function looks like.

Comment: The most efficient would be to pre-allocate an array of the right result type (and ideally right size), which is what I expect `map` does.

Comment: If there is always a first value of `alive`, you could initialize the vector as `result = [alive]`.